# PictureScrollField in BlackBerry

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I want to create a PictureScrollField using some images in Blackberry.By default it is displayed on the top of the screen with the given width and height.
But if we want to display the entire one  at certain coordinates say(x,y),then how to align them.

Answer (score 0):

add the picture scroll field in a horizontal field manager and align the manager